# I want to change background image pattern on page refresh. i have tried many codes but not working as i required

Tags: javascript, php, css

Here is my complete code i want to change image on page refresh. here is the code that i am using but its not working.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    var theImages = new Array()

    theImages[0] = 'images/1.png'
    theImages[1] = 'images/2.png'
    theImages[2] = 'images/3.png'

    var j = 0
    var p = theImages.length;
    var preBuffer = new Array()

    for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
        preBuffer[i] = new Image()
        preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
    }
    var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

    function showImage(){
        if(whichImage==0){
            document.write('<a href ="link.html">
            <img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'"');
        }
        else if(whichImage==1){
            document.write('<a href ="link.html">
            <img   src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'"');
        }
        else if(whichImage==2){
            document.write('<a href ="link.html">
            <img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'"');
        }
        else if(whichImage==3){
            document.write('<a href ="link.html">
           <img  src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'"');

        }
        else if(whichImage==4){
            document.write('<a href ="link.html">
            <img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'"');
        }


    }
</SCRIPT>
```

..here is my html code where i want to change that images. where i have called script function.

```
<div  class="under_header" style="height:600px;margin-top:0px;     background:url(<script>showImage();</script>) ,  url(images/latest_movie/<?php echo $movie_image; ?>) center 76px fixed no-repeat; -moz-background-size:auto, over; background-size:auto, cover; 

box-shadow: inset 945px 0px 645px -645px black, inset -945px 0px 645px -645px black;">                                

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't put a `script` tag inside a style attribute's CSS string.

Try something like this in the JavaScript, not in the CSS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("under_header")[0].style.background = "url("+showImage()+") ,  url(images/latest_movie/<?php echo $movie_image; ?>) center 76px fixed no-repeat";
```

Comment: Hi  thanks for your ans but it is not working or i dont know where to  put that code please suggest through my code as i posted in question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already solved your problem, but as Jacques said your way of calling the script won't work.

checking the value of "whichImage" is unnecessary, you could do something like this:

```
function showImage() {
  $('.under_header').append('<a href ="link.html"><img src="' + theImages[whichImage] + '"></a>');
```

}

Here is a fiddle, people loves fiddles.
https://jsfiddle.net/Sprazer/va9j5sb0/

I am sorry for using jQuery

Comment: Hi thanks for your ans but it is not working or i dont know where to put that code please suggest through my code as i posted in question

Comment: @RahulNaik Sorry didn't not fully read your question when I answered, but Ciriprian got the full solution above.

Answer (score 1):

The way you try to combine javascript and css will not work. The example below randomly sets a background image to the target div.

The function `showImage` is called on the `onload` event. So, every time you refresh the page, that div will have a different background image.

Use this example to build whatever functionality you want on page refresh.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            var theImages = new Array();

            theImages[0] = 'images/1.jpg';
            theImages[1] = 'images/2.jpg';
            theImages[2] = 'images/3.jpg';

            var p = theImages.length;
            var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

            function showImage(){
                document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundImage="url('" + theImages[whichImage] + "')";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="showImage()">

        <div id="myDiv" style="width:300px; height: 200px;" />

    </body>

</html>
```